# Mother and Son in Harmony

Tags: lateral-thinking

A boy's father dies leaving his mother to be a poor widow.  A few years later the boy marries his mother legally.

How is this possible?

Hint:

> It is all done in good faith

Comment: Untranslatable :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The boy conducts a marriage ceremony between his mother and her new spouse.

Answer (score 2):

The boy was adopted, so it would not be incest.

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't be incest, but I'm not sure that is legal.  And it doesn't fit with the hint.

Answer (score 2):

The boy is obviously

> [Oedipus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus)

He did it in good faith so it even fits the hint.

Comment: Okay - you got me on that one; he did marry his mother in good faith (sort of).  My only counter-argument is that Oedipus was more than a boy when he *killed* his father.